# Hyper-v cannot connect to local computer

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

When I open Hyper-V Manager it is not connected to any servers. When I try to connect to my local computer I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wi9X.png), saying Hyper-v cannot access and object, and asks if Virtual Machine Management service is running, [It is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT9wJ.png).

Hyper-v worked on my machine a few days ago, and I do not believe I have made any changes to my computer in the mean time.

What I have tried:

- I have disabled and enabled Hyper-v in 'Turn windows features on and off'
- I have deleted the files in "ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines"
- I have deleted the files in "Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks"
- I have run sfc and dism to check for issues (it did not find any)

I am just trying to be able to have a local virtual machine. I am not trying to connect to any other computers/servers.

At this point I have no idea of what to try next. Other than making a fresh windows install on my computer (which I would like to avoid).

I am running windows 10 pro 64 bit, version: 1709, OS build: 16299.125

Comment: I have a same issue, I suspect Windows Fall Creators Update has screwed the user rights. It worked last time I tried in summer before the update. You can try adding yourself to Hyper-V Admin group from `lusrmgr.msc`, it didn't work for me yet.

Comment: @Ciantic: thanks, this looks like it's a problem for me- the group is empty now

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue, can you help ? How did you solve this problem? @Daluur

Comment: @AditiB At the time I did not get it to work. Just now I tried adding myself to the Hyper-V admin group as suggested by Ciantic which seemed to work. 
I am however facing a different issue, where enabling Hyper-V disconnects me from the internet. It seems like the network adapter/driver simply shuts off. 
Back when I had the issue originally I ended up using VirtualBox instead.

Comment: Even I did the same. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal with admin privilegies and run:

- sc config vmms start=auto
- sc start vmms

Read about this solution on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/best-practices-analyzer/the-hyper-v-virtual-machine-management-service-must-be-running